# Scraping information using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to get some information regarding the following fields:

```
Website Address 
Last Analysis
Blacklist Status
Domain Registration
Server Location
```

from this website:

https://www.urlvoid.com/scan/gordonramsay.com/

I have used requests and BeautifulSoup to have access t the website and scrape information:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.urlvoid.com/scan/gordonramsay.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
```

However I have not been able to select those fields. 
These fields should be added as individual columns in a dataset. 
Do you have any suggestion on how to get that info and adding as column's fields?

Any help is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
tab = soup.select("table.table.table-custom.table-striped")
dat = tab[0].select('tr')
for d in dat:
    row = d.select('td')
    print(row[0].text,' ',row[1].text)
```

Output:

```
Website Address   Gordonramsay.com
Last Analysis   5 years ago  |   Rescan
Blacklist Status   0/34
Domain Registration   2000-02-03 | 20 years ago
Domain Information    WHOIS Lookup | DNS Records | Ping
IP Address   89.206.225.168   Find Websites  |  IPVoid  |  Whois
Reverse DNS   unallocated.star.net.uk
ASN   AS6656 Star Technology Services Limited
Server Location    (GB) United Kingdom
Latitude\Longitude   51.9864 / -4.5578    Google Map
City   Star
Region   Pembrokeshire
```

If you want to output only the 5 specific entries, use this:

```
tab2 = soup.select("table.table.table-custom.table-striped tr")
targets = ['Website Address', 'Last Analysis', 'Blacklist Status', 'Domain Registration', 'Server Location']
for t in tab2:
    item = t.select('td')
    if len(item)==2 and item[0].text in targets:
        print(item[0].text, ' ', item[1].text)
```

Output:

```
Website Address   Gordonramsay.com
Last Analysis   5 years ago  |   Rescan
Blacklist Status   0/34
Domain Registration   2000-02-03 | 20 years ago
Server Location    (GB) United Kingdom
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Jack.

Comment: @Val Glad it helped!

Comment: Hi Jack, just one quick question: how can I iterate over different queries? I tried the following:

`queries=['bbc.com','bbc.co.uk', 'thesun']
for x in queries:
        query=x
        r = requests.get('https://www.urlvoid.com/scan/'+x+'.it/')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        tab = soup.select("table.table.table-custom.table-striped")
        dat = tab[0].select('tr')
        for d in dat:
            row = d.select('td')
            print(row[0].text,' ',row[1].text)
        c += 1`
but it does not work because `dat = tab[0].select('tr')` is out of range.

Comment: @Val In your `requests.get('https://www.urlvoid.com/scan/'+x+'.it/')`, what is the `.it` at the end? Are you looking, for example, for `bbc.com.it`?

Comment: sorry it was a typo. Thank you for spotting the error!

Comment: @Val - I tried it and it worked for me - expect for `thesun`; I suspect the reason is that this is also a typo: it sould be `thesun.com`.

Comment: Yes, It works @Jack. It was the typo because of .it at the end. I am trying to collect information into array for each url.

Comment: Hi @Jack Fleeting, I got  `IndexError: list index out of range`  at `---> 18         dat = tab[0].select('tr')` when I have been trying with a list of urls. Do you know why it happens? I have fixed it using exception.

Comment: Hi @Jack Fleeting. I opened a new question on how to add new columns to my existing dataset with the information scraped from that website. Maybe you might have a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037401/creating-new-columns-by-scraping-information

Comment: @Val - I did; check the answer.