# Web-scraping: Empty dataset after collecting information

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to create a dataset that includes information scraped from a website. I explain what I have done and the expected output below. I am getting empty arrays for rows and columns, then for the whole dataset, and I do not understand the reason. I hope you can help me.

1) Create an empty dataframe with only one column: this columns should contains a list of urls to use.

```
data_to_use = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['URL'])
```

2) Select urls from a previous dataset.

```
select_urls=dataset.URL.tolist()
```

This set of urls looks like:

```
                             URL
0                     www.bbc.co.uk
1             www.stackoverflow.com           
2                       www.who.int
3                       www.cnn.com
4         www.cooptrasportiriolo.it
...                             ...
```

3) Populate the column with these urls:

```
data_to_use['URL']= select_urls
data_to_use['URLcleaned'] = data_to_use['URL'].str.replace('^(www\.)', '')
```

4) Select a random sample to test: the first `50` rows in column `URL`

```
data_to_use = data_to_use.loc[1:50, 'URL']
```

5) Try to scrape information

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls= data_to_use['URLcleaned'].tolist()

ares = []

for u in urls: # in the selection there should be an error. I am not sure that I am selecting the rig
    print(u)
    url = 'https://www.urlvoid.com/scan/'+ u
    r = requests.get(url)
    ares.append(r)   

rows = []
cols = []

for ar in ares:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ar.content, 'lxml')
    tab = soup.select("table.table.table-custom.table-striped")   
    try:
            dat = tab[0].select('tr')
            line= []
            header=[]
            for d in dat:
                row = d.select('td')
                line.append(row[1].text)
            new_header = row[0].text
            if not new_header in cols:
                cols.append(new_header)
            rows.append(line)
    except IndexError:
        continue

print(rows) # this works fine. It prints the rows. The issue comes from the next line

data_to_use = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=cols)
```

Unfortunately there is something wrong in the steps above as I am not getting any results, but only `[]` or `__`.

Error from `data_to_use = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=cols)`:

```
ValueError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 12 columns
```

My expected output would be:

```
URL          Website Address   Last Analysis   Blacklist Status \  
bbc.co.uk          Bbc.co.uk         9 days ago       0/35
stackoverflow.com Stackoverflow.com  7 days ago      0/35

Domain Registration               IP Address       Server Location    ...
996-08-01 | 24 years ago       151.101.64.81    (US) United States    ...
2003-12-26 | 17 years ago      ...
```

At the end I should save the dataset created in a file csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting aside the conversion to csv, let's try it this way:

```
urls=['gov.ie', 'who.int', 'comune.staranzano.go.it', 'cooptrasportiriolo.it', 'laprovinciadicomo.it', 'asufc.sanita.fvg.it', 'canale7.tv', 'gradenigo.it', 'leggo.it', 'urbanpost.it', 'monitorimmobiliare.it', 'comune.villachiara.bs.it', 'ilcittadinomb.it', 'europamulticlub.com']
ares = []
for u in urls:
    url = 'https://www.urlvoid.com/scan/'+u
    r = requests.get(url)
    ares.append(r)
```

Note that 3 of the urls have no data, so you should have only 11 rows in the dataframe.
Next:

```
rows = []
cols = []
for ar in ares:
    soup = bs(ar.content, 'lxml')
    tab = soup.select("table.table.table-custom.table-striped")        
    if len(tab)>0:
        dat = tab[0].select('tr')
        line= []
        header=[]
        for d in dat:
            row = d.select('td')
            line.append(row[1].text)
            new_header = row[0].text
            if not new_header in cols:
                cols.append(new_header)
        rows.append(line)

my_df = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=cols)   
my_df.info()
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 11 entries, 0 to 10
Data columns (total 12 columns):
Website Address        11 non-null object
Last Analysis          11 non-null object
Blacklist Status       11 non-null object
Domain Registration    11 non-null object
Domain Information     11 non-null object
IP Address             11 non-null object
Reverse DNS            11 non-null object
ASN                    11 non-null object
Server Location        11 non-null object
Latitude\Longitude     11 non-null object
City                   11 non-null object
Region                 11 non-null object
dtypes: object(12)
memory usage: 1.2+ KB
```

Answer (score 1):

Yon can do it using pandas only.Try the following code.

```
urllist=[ 'bbc.co.uk','stackoverflow.com','who.int','cnn.com']

dffinal=pd.DataFrame()
for url in urllist:
    df=pd.read_html("https://www.urlvoid.com/scan/" + url + "/")[0]
    list = df.values.tolist()
    rows = []
    cols = []
    for li in list:
        rows.append(li[1])
        cols.append(li[0])
    df1=pd.DataFrame([rows],columns=cols)
    dffinal = dffinal.append(df1, ignore_index=True)

print(dffinal)
dffinal.to_csv("domain.csv",index=False)
```

**Csv snapshot:**

[image]

Snapshot.

[image]

Csv file.

[image]

---

**Update** with `try..except` block since some of the url doesn't return data.

```
urllist=['gov.ie','','who.int', 'comune.staranzano.go.it', 'cooptrasportiriolo.it', 'laprovinciadicomo.it', 'asufc.sanita.fvg.it', 'canale7.tv', 'gradenigo.it', 'leggo.it', 'urbanpost.it', 'monitorimmobiliare.it', 'comune.villachiara.bs.it', 'ilcittadinomb.it', 'europamulticlub.com']

dffinal=pd.DataFrame()
for url in urllist:
    try:
        df=pd.read_html("https://www.urlvoid.com/scan/" + url + "/")[0]
        list = df.values.tolist()
        rows = []
        cols = []
        for li in list:
            rows.append(li[1])
            cols.append(li[0])
        df1=pd.DataFrame([rows],columns=cols)
        dffinal = dffinal.append(df1, ignore_index=True)

    except:
        continue

print(dffinal)
dffinal.to_csv("domain.csv",index=False)
```

**Console**:

```
            Website Address  ...         Region
0                     Gov.ie  ...         Dublin
1                    Who.int  ...         Geneva
2    Comune.staranzano.go.it  ...        Unknown
3      Cooptrasportiriolo.it  ...        Unknown
4       Laprovinciadicomo.it  ...        Unknown
5                 Canale7.tv  ...        Unknown
6                   Leggo.it  ...          Milan
7               Urbanpost.it  ...  Ile-de-France
8      Monitorimmobiliare.it  ...        Unknown
9   Comune.villachiara.bs.it  ...        Unknown
10          Ilcittadinomb.it  ...        Unknown

[11 rows x 12 columns]
```

Comment: nany thanks dear KunduK for this bright an convincing solutinon

Comment: Thank you KunduK. To double check, I have tried with this other list too: `urllist =[ 'gov.ie','who.int','comune.staranzano.go.it','cooptrasportiriolo.it']`
and I have got the following error: `ValueError: No tables found`. Could you please check if it works for you? Thanks.

Comment: @val : Yes I am getting all the value.

Comment: @KunduK, thank you for checking it. Do you know why I am getting this error? I have tried to write them, not copying and pasting, in order to avoid encoding issues. Could you please update the question with this dataset too?

Comment: @val :  I don't see any problem at my end.You have to check at your end.I can  guide you only how to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you KunduK. I will continue to check it. Maybe it is a bug as with the initial dataset it works well. Thank you so much. You already did a lot.

Comment: @Val :Possibly that could be.

Comment: @KunduK: II think there is a problem with this function : `df=pd.read_html("https://www.urlvoid.com/scan/" + url)[0]` I get `HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found` but the urls are correct. I am using the following list: `urls=['gov.ie', '', 'who.int', 'comune.staranzano.go.it', 'cooptrasportiriolo.it', 'laprovinciadicomo.it', 'asufc.sanita.fvg.it', 'canale7.tv', 'gradenigo.it', 'leggo.it', 'urbanpost.it',  'monitorimmobiliare.it', 'comune.villachiara.bs.it', 'ilcittadinomb.it', 'europamulticlub.com']` - What was wrong in my initial code that could not be fixed?

Comment: This `df=pd.read_html("https://www.urlvoid.com/scan/" + url)[0]` also causes No tables found error. Do you know why? Would it be possible to consider another way to scrape information? For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037401/creating-new-columns-by-scraping-information/61045873?noredirect=1#comment108000119_61045873

Comment: @Val : If you see your url list there is one blank url and some of the url if you hit on browser you will see there is no table.That is the reason you are getting the error.You can use the same code with try..except block if table not found continue.Hope this helps.I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to @KunduK's solution. You can condense part of that code using pandas' `.T` (transpose function).

So you can turn this part:

```
df=pd.read_html("https://www.urlvoid.com/scan/" + url + "/")[0]
list = df.values.tolist()
rows = []
cols = []
for li in list:
    rows.append(li[1])
    cols.append(li[0])
df1=pd.DataFrame([rows],columns=cols)
dffinal = dffinal.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
```

Into simply:

```
df=pd.read_html("https://www.urlvoid.com/scan/" + url + "/")[0].set_index(0).T
dffinal = dffinal.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```